# Limit or Good-Practice Handle of Large Amounts of Logs

Tags: linux, logs

I've got 3 files in my Linux system that logs informations in `/var/log/` and tend to get big for the amount of size I have available.

**Thoses files are :**

- *kernel.log*
- *sys.log*
- *messages*

My solution was to create a `ln -s [file] /dev/null`. Is it a good way to do ? Or is there another *better* way to limit the size of those files so that I can keep the latest available data in those files instead of throwing it ?

**Note :** I do not have `logrotated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting logs to `/dev/null` isn't the way to go.

- Rotate your logs using whatever mechanism your distribution provides
- OR configure the logging facility in a way to produce less noise (set your loglevel accordingly)
- OR - if you're sure you don't need these logs - configure the logger to just not log to those files.